# Where can I ask for academic advisement specific to my situation (low gpa, grad school, etc)?

Tags: gpa

I'd pay for personal, not snarky, but honest feedback. I don't really want to post all the specifics online- I would like to keep it confidential.

Is there a **place** online that you could recommend where I can keep this info private? Or a person, who I can pay for advice like this? I know others have asked abot low gpa + grad-school, however one story does not fit all. I am asking for a person to talk to about my situation and is knowledgeable of the graduate admissions process.

Comment: The best academic advisory comes directly from staff at your institution.

Comment: I believe my advisers sugar-coat too much instead of telling me what I need to know.

Comment: There are professional academic coaches such as Karen Kelsky (http://theprofessorisin.com)

Answer (score 1):

The admissions, placement, and/or graduate departments of your previous institution(s) have a vested interest in your success, actually, and usually provide such advice. If there is no formal process, which it sounds like you'd want to avoid, find a *trustworthy* professor. Tell them what you need. Ask them not to sugar coat it.

Failing that, a knowledgeable and honest friend makes a great councilor.

The admissions and chosen departments of your ultimate dream program *also* have a vested interest in telling you what you need to do to get in, but they are focused keeping out bad candidates; They are more likely to err on the side of "shoo", so if you suspect a smokey skirt from your home faculty, talk to someone where you are heading.